# Supported Orientation, Monogame, Windows Phone 8

Tags: xna, c#, monogame, windows-phone-8

I am developing a game in which I need to rotate the screen on Landscape mode or Portrait, and lock it that way.

In Monogame, targeting Windows Phone **8.1** adding this code:

```
Graphics.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.LandscapeLeft | DisplayOrientation.LandscapeRight;
            Graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

Was enough, but in Monogame, targeting Windows Phone **8** I can switch from Portrait mode to Landscape, even if I put the code above in the game constructor.

How can I stop/freeze the user from chaning the orientations on a specific category in my game?

Thanks.

Comment: Does windows phone have an `activity` ?  In android I use `ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.SensorLandscape;` and it does what you describe. The user can rotate left/right keeping landscape mode at all times. I have no experience with windows phone unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your package manifest. There should be the options for screen orientation. Uncheck the portrait.